# Why does the line number in the console not match the line number in the code?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Why does the line number in the console not match the line number in the code?

[image]

But if you comment out the string ' Util.promisify(Hg.clone);`, then there is no error with the line number.

[image]

How to fix?

Comment: It is not by chance due to the fact that the module `hg` does not have a file with a description of the types under the `typescript`?
Or maybe due to the fact that `hg` is written on `coffee-script`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the problem. It turns out the module `hg` is written to `coffeescript`. And it compiles during the execution of the script. And because of him such problems.

I compiled it. And inserted already in the compiled form. And the problem disappeared. Now all the lines match!!!